# Unable to bring up attributes for a feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes

When I select the layer in question as the only selectable layer, I am able to use Open Attribute Table and open the attribute table for the **entire layer**.  However, when I right click a feature in the layer and select Attributes, the Attribute window on the right side remains blank.

Note that when I select any other layer, and do the above, I get the individual Attributes for that feature, as you would expect.

I've looked at attribute settings and have tried to vary things in the layer Properties, to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the source of your troublesome layer?  Are you able to reproduce your problem when just that layer is added to a blank map?

Comment: One of my counterparts in a collaborating company.  I didn't try adding it to a blank map although I will do so.  However, I still think it is strange that I can get the entire attribute table for the layer, but not the individual attribute table for an individual feature.  Especially when I can do so for all of the other layers on the map.

Comment: It’s always good to list your steps from starting ArcMap to when you think it’s started to misbehave.

Comment: By source I meant the type of workspace for the feature class you added to create that layer.

Comment: Draw a box, don't click if you want to select.

Comment: We finally figured it out.  My colleague was taking my geodatabase and converting it to layers in order for the field workers to use Field Maps.  Although he was converting it back to a geodatabase to send me, nothing worked until he converted back into the original geodatabase and sent that to me.  That finally solved the problem!
Thanks for your help and comments everyone!